# Are there any problems with JSP for a new greenfield project?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, template-engine

It seems, that [JSP is regarded as deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482852/is-jsp-really-considered-deprecated) or de-facto abandoned:

- There is [no ecosystem around JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645413/what-are-useful-and-actively-maintained-jsp-tag-libraries). Most taglibs on the net are abandoned.
- The last Java EE tutorial that included [JSP was for Java EE version 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845032/wheres-the-official-jsp-tutorial).
- "JSP technology is considered to be a deprecated presentation technology for JavaServer Faces." ([Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html))

I'm still thinking about using JSP for a new project. I can't find anything wrong with it from a technical point of view. But I read that there are [major problems with JSF](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/why_the_bias_against_jsf):

- It's too slow for sites with a lot of traffic. (citation needed)
- It's hard to get full control over the generated HTML for design centric web sites. (citation needed)
- JSF relies on server state what [I'd like to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510591/use-spring-web-flow-without-state-on-the-server).
- JSF is much more than a template engine but I want just a view layer technologie.

Are there any technical or conceptual problems with JSP as a templating system that I should be aware of?
I know that there are also velocity, freemarker, thymeleaf, jade4j but I don't see their (major) advantage over JSP. I intend to disable scriptlets and use spring MVC. I know that traditional JSP usage with scriptlets and without MVC is indeed a problem.

Comment: *It's too slow for sites with a lot of traffic* that's false, that's the case of bad designed JSF applications. *It's hard to get full control over the generated HTML for design centric web sites.* that's a personal opinion, IMO I have full control of the generated HTML since I understand how JSF and other components gets rendered so I can do what I need as much as I want, of course if I want to create HTML components on the fly, JSF maybe is not the right tool.

Comment: *JSF relies on server state* you can change this since Mojarra 2.1.19 or using JSF 2.2, refer to  [Stateless JSF](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/02/stateless-jsf.html). *JSF is much more than a template engine but I want just a view layer technology* Do a proof of concept about what you want/need using plain JSP and your MVC framework (or maybe using servlets only) and using JSF and Facelets, then decide.

Comment: For a Spring MVC project always use JSP because it has the best support. I don't know much about the other view technologies, but Velocity gave me some headaches with handling forms and rendering views with javascript embedded containing the `$` symbol. Problems I don't encounter when using JSP.